# Allow docker swarm service to bind host ip interface

Tags: docker, ubuntu, networking, devops, docker-swarm

I create a go script who switch between IP linked to my eno1 interface.

In case my program perform a `curl --interface "51.15.xx.xx" ...` and switch between my 3 IPs

Bellow my interface :

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether ac:1f:6b:27:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 51.15.xx.xx/24 brd 51.15.21.255 scope global eno1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 212.83.xx.x1/24 brd 212.83.154.255 scope global eno1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 212.83.xx.x2/24 brd 212.83.154.255 scope global secondary eno1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My program run perfectly when he run on host directly, he work too on 
`docker run --network=host`.

But in production with a docker swarm (deployed on 1 node), i can't bind host network and my program can't run. I get the error: `bind failed with errno 99: Address not available`

I just want to bind `host` network with local scope on a swarm service or allow my swarm service to bind host ip

PS: I already try to bind network host but when I execute `docker stack deploy`, docker select a `host` network with scope swarm.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you publish a port when declaring your swarm service or stack ?

According to the documentation:

> If your container or service publishes no ports, host networking has no effect.

See https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: Yes I did, I publish 1 port

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a direct command to create service, for example:

**Code**

```
docker service create --network host caa06d9c/echo
```

Docker image does not expose any ports

**Check**

```
curl localhost:8080
```

**Output**

```
{
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/",
    "ip": "127.0.0.1"
}
```

So port attached to the host and can be accessed from any interfaces.